# What would be the easiest way to display a bunch of images from a web server in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview

My app is needing the ability to get multiple images from a web server / directory (i.e. www.somedomain.com/images/). The number of images will never be the same, and I will not have access to the names of the files because they will also never be the same. The end result I'm looking for is to give my client the ability to just access her sub directory through her ftp client and just drop images into the specified folder without having to name the images a certain name, write any xml files, or any other steps beyond dragging the images into the folder. Then my clients users that log into the app will be able to get the images that my client has placed into that directory. I have been looking into Apple's simpleFTPsample project to get access via FTP. I just want to know if there are any other simpler options? One reason being: simpleFTPsample style requires an FTP username and password to access those files. I'm not 100% sure if it is safe to place the user and pass within the app. Any suggestions or samples would be great thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a simple UIWebView that is set up when you search thru the original dir with a simple GET?

Comment: If you're displaying the images don't forget to use lazy loading, or else your app can become a data usage hog.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by lazy loading? Only loading when it's ready to be displayed? or something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend putting a simple PHP script that lists the images into the same HTML directory as the images.  You can then download all the images in the directory using simple NSURLConnection calls, based on the output of hitting the listing script.

Something like [this.](http://www.laughing-buddha.net/php/dirlist/)

```
<?php

    $directory = "."; // Use your directory here

    // create a handler for the directory
    $handler = opendir($directory);

    // open directory and walk through the filenames
    while ($file = readdir($handler)) {

      // if file isn't this directory or its parent, add it to the results
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        echo "$file\n";
      }

    }

    // tidy up: close the handler
    closedir($handler);
?>
```

If there is some sort of security you can use .htaccess in the directory to provide a login barrier, and provide the credentials using your NSURLConnection.

Good luck.

Comment: I didn't want to have to write any kind of script or file to handle the images. Because my client will be changing the images periodically and won't know how to deal with any coding. So I would like to make it as simple as possible by enabling her to just drag and drop the images into the folder on the server.

Comment: I re-read your answer again and realized that I read it wrong the first time. I was playing around with it getting it to list the directory items on the web but I haven't tried to read it from within the app. Everything seems like it should work. I'll accept your answer after I successfully implement it in the app. Thanks

Comment: Thanks man, I am constantly reminded of the power of PHP haha.

Answer (score 0):

based on how you will use the images perhaps best bet would be to create a webservice that provides you with the images and corresponding urls.  This would provide a solution to allow your client's users to get the images without needing to know anything about FTPs and be shown only the images for a given directory or directories.  That setup would would allow you to then load the images based on your response, and use them as you need.  Here is a small bit of sample code to load the images asynchronously in a tableview cell.

```
// load thumbnail images off main thread
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        // backgroung processing
        UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourURL"]]];

        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // background processing complete
            [[(TableCell *) cell image] setImage:thumbnail];
            [[cell activityIndicator] stopAnimating];

            // if row selected before image loaded 
            if ([indexPath row] == [[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]) {
                 if (!iPhone) {
                     [myButton setBackgroundImage:thumbnail forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                 }
             }
        });
    });
```

I've created a sample webservice project that may help you to architect the service response that is available on github at https://github.com/propstm/SampleWeatherApp

Comment: I need for it to access the entire directory of images and I won't have access to all the image URL's because they will always be changing.

Comment: If you can call a webservice to return all images and directory paths at that point in time it will work.  The service should execute when you start the app and return the image paths that currently exist.